# Why cannot marshal struct with auto layout

Tags: c#, .net, struct, interop, marshalling

I encountered an odd behaviour when marshalling a struct with auto layout kind.

For example: let's take a simple code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
public struct StructAutoLayout
{
    byte B1;
    long Long1;
    byte B2;
    long Long2;
    byte B3;
}
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sizeof struct is {0}", Marshal.SizeOf<StructAutoLayout>());
}
```

it throws an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Type
>   'StructAutoLayout' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged
>   structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

So it means that compiler doesn't know struct size at compile time? I was sure that this attribute reorders struct fields and then compiles it, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense. Marshalling is used for interop - and when doing interop, the two sides have to agree *exactly* on the structure of the `struct`.

When you use auto layout, you defer the decision about the structure layout to the compiler. Even different versions of the same compiler can result in different layouts - that's a problem. For example, one compiler might use this:

```
public struct StructAutoLayout
{
    byte B1;
    long Long1;
    byte B2;
    long Long2;
    byte B3;
}
```

while another might do something like this:

```
public struct StructAutoLayout
{
    byte B1;
    byte B2;
    byte B3;
    byte _padding;
    long Long1;
    long Long2;
}
```

When dealing with native/unmanaged code, there's pretty much no meta-data involved - just pointers and values. The other side has no way of knowing how the structure is actually laid out, it *expects* a fixed layout you both agreed upon in advance.

.NET has a tendency to make you spoiled - almost everything *just works*. This is not the case when interoping with something like C++ - if you just guess your way around, you'll most likely end up with a solution that usually works, but once in a while crashes your whole application. When doing anything with unmanaged / native code, make sure you understand perfectly what you're doing - unmanaged interop is just fragile that way.

Now, the `Marshal` class is designed *specifically* for unmanaged interop. If you read the documentation for `Marshal.SizeOf`, it specifically says

> Returns the size of an unmanaged type in bytes.

And of course,

> You can use this method when you do not have a structure. The layout must be sequential or explicit.
>
> The size returned is the size of the unmanaged type. The unmanaged and managed sizes of an object can differ. For character types, the size is affected by the CharSet value applied to that class.

If the type *can't* possibly be marshalled, what should `Marshal.SizeOf` return? That doesn't even make sense :)

Asking for the size of a type or an instance doesn't make any sense in a managed environment. "Real size in memory" is an implementation detail as far as you are concerned - it's not a part of the contract, and it's not something to rely on. If the runtime / compiler wanted, it could make every `byte` 77 bytes long, and it wouldn't break any contract whatsoever as long as it only stores values from 0 to 255 exactly.

If you used a `struct` with an explicit (or sequential) layout instead, you would have a definite contract for how the unmanaged type is laid out, and `Marshal.SizeOf` would work. However, even then, it will only return the size of the unmanaged type, not of the managed one - that can still differ. And again, both can be different on different systems (for example, `IntPtr` will be four bytes on a 32-bit system and eight bytes on a 64-bit system when running as a 64-bit application).

Another important point is that there's multiple levels of "compilation" in a .NET application. The first level, using a C# compiler, is only the tip of the iceberg - and it's *not* the part that handles reordering fields in the auto-layout structs. It simply marks the struct as "auto-layouted", and it's done. The actual layouting is handled when you run the application by the CLI (the specification is not clear on whether the JIT compiler handles that, but I would assume so). But that has nothing to do with `Marshal.SizeOf` or even `sizeof` - both of those are still handled at runtime. Forget everything you know from C++ - C# (and even C++/CLI) is an entirely different beast.

If you need to profile managed memory, use a memory profiler (like CLRProfiler). But do understand that you're still profiling memory in a very specific environment - different systems or .NET versions can give you different results. And in fact, there's nothing saying two instances of the same structure must be the same size.

Comment: "The **runtime** automatically chooses an appropriate layout for the members of an object in unmanaged memory". Not a compiler. That's a problem.

Comment: @Dennis Well, it's handled by the CLI, but it's not clear which part. I'd expect the JIT compiler is the one who decides. But that doesn't really matter - even if it were the C# compiler, it would still mean the type would be dangerous and useless for unmanaged interop.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't sense to interop with struct like this. But this question born from another: I just couldn't get exact struct size. I don't want to transfer it into C++ app or so on, I just was suprised that even CLR doesn't know what actual size struct is.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy `Marshal.SizeOf` doesn't tell you the size of the structure! You're in a managed memory environment, and things like "size in memory" are implementation details you shouldn't ever rely on. The point of `Marshal.SizeOf` is to give you the size of the structure *when marshalled for unmanaged/native interop*. When it throws that exception, it's trying to protect you from yourself - whatever value it would return would be meaningless and dangerous. If you need to do memory profiling, use a memory profiler, not `Marshal.SizeOf`.

Comment: @Luaan well, "use memory profiler" sounds resonable, but anyway I don't think that it's `meaningless and dangerous`. For example in case of writing custom memory manager. Common answer is `Language is not designed for it, use C++ and so on`, but it's not a real answer. Sometimes we need this "implementation detail".

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy If you need this implementation detail, use explicit structure layouts and unsafe code. But yes, if you need to do this for most of your code, you should try some unmanaged language instead. Custom memory management in C# is usually used for reusable data (e.g. `byte[]` buffers, structures...) and unsafe code. For anything else, just note that whatever you optimize for, it's going to be environment specific, and it's likely going to blow up in your face when something changes. It's like coding in C while using inline assembler - it works, but you lose some.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy The point is, *really*, if you *need* deterministic memory management, C# simply isn't the right tool for the job. If Systems-C# is ever released, it might be a better choice, but that's not ready yet. As long as you're using C#, you must accept that you're delegating memory management responsibility to the runtime, and you lose some control as a result. Of course, even C++ takes a lot of control from you - as does running on a multi-tasking, virtualized-memory OS in the first place.